# PHP Array for Redirecting Pages

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have a PHP file called redirects.php which I am using to redirect particular requests, however I have around 150 pages I need to redirect to different, new pages. My code so far is this:

```
if (isset($_GET['req'])) {
  $req = $_GET['req'];
  $redirect = "";

  if ($req == "quoter_buying_guides.php") {
    $redirect = "newpage";
    $loc = "http://www.example.co.uk/" . $redirect;
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: " .$loc. "");
  }
}
```

Copying the if ($req == "") {... is getting very long winded and making the file rather large. I'd like to be able to do this in one array line for example:

```
"old-page.php" => "new-page.php
"old-page2.php" => "new-page2.php";
```

Before anyone mentions using the .htaccess file to perform redirects - I would normally have done however we're using a complicated pager file which ignores 301 requests.

Comment: Have you considered keeping the redirects in a database and simply querying the one you need to get back a single record of where to send the user?

Comment: You have the correct idea. So what is the problem? Array access is a pretty trivial issue.

Comment: @Fluffeh: How is querying a database different than querying an array in this context, apart from the fact that it introduces extra complexity? We 're talking a couple hundred pages, which is a trivial amount of data.

Comment: @Jon The OP mentions that the file is getting very long already, as it gets longer, it is only going to make redirects harder and harder to keep track of. If you pop them into a db, you can not only keep them in order, but also very easily track redirect counts or dates.

Comment: @Fluffeh: I don't know about that. My text editor's "find" feature works at least as well as a SELECT and it's also more convenient.  There's also no mention of any need to keep counts or dates. Deploying a database from scratch just to store this kind of information is overkill, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Jon I am just offering a slightly different suggestion. If I had a list that was never going to exceed 150, I probably wouldn't do it either, but if it was going to balloon up to 1,500 or 15,000 I would be wanting a more maintainable solution. I have many arrays hard-coded, but I also use many queries to get data for this sort of thing. But really, I don't want to argue with you sir, it was just a suggestion :)

Comment: @Fluffeh: And I just wanted to make sure we 're not over-engineering here. No worries, have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers! Sander seemed to have the answer I was looking for although I noticed many of you responded with a similar solution using an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like you say, use an array.

You can use the same key as what you provide in the $_GET['req']

```
//Define all redirects here
$redirects = array();
$redirects['quoter_buying_guides.php'] = 'new-page.php';
$redirects['key2'] = 'new-page2.php';

//Or like this
$redirects = array(
   'quoter_buying_guides.php' => 'new-page.php',
   'key2' => 'new-page2.php'
);

//Here we do the actual redirect
if(isset($_GET['req']) && isset($redirects[$_GET['req']])) {
    $loc = "http://www.example.co.uk/" . $redirects[$_GET['req']];
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: " . $loc);
    exit();
}
//Nice to have
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
```

Comment: Thanks Sander! This soluton worked perfectly and saved me a hell of a lot of time. I had an exported CSV of over 150 URL's which I was literally able to paste into my redirects.php file and build the array around it and redirect each individual page to the relevant, corresponding page. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, just want to say, thanks for this! I've worked on this to be able to be used for wildcard redirects too which is absolutely perfect. [Here's my answer on my thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69880990/9356914) with the full gem of a script it is :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class that checks the DB for a match or otherwise uses a default redirection to send to - or perhaps does not redirect:

```
<?php

    class redirecto
    {
        public $outLoc;
        public function __construct($input)
        {
            // Here you run a query to get the matching 
            // redirection from a database
            // or return false/empty when not found.
            $redirect='http://www.example.com';

            if(redirect)
            {
                $outLoc = "http://www.example.co.uk/" . $redirect;
            }
            else
            {
                $outLoc = "http://www.example.co.uk/someDefault";
            }
            header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
            header("Location: " .$outLoc. "");
        }
    }

    $checkRedirect=new redirecto($yourRequest);

?>
```

If you do want to keep it inside the file itself, you can do a quick array_search() to get the right value back:

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        "old-page.php" => "new-page.php"
        "old-page2.php" => "new-page2.php",
        );

    $redirect = array_search('old-page.php', $array);

    if($redirect)
    {
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: " .$redirect. "");
    }
    else
    {
        // either no redirect or default location.
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['req'])) {
  $req = $_GET['req'];

  $redirs = array ('quoter_buying_guides.php' => 'http://www.example.co.uk/newpage',
                   'foo' => 'http://www.example.co.uk/bar');
  header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
  header("Location: " .$redirs[$req] . "");
}
```

It'd probably be easier to read the array in from a flat file.

Comment: This assumes that the requested url is always set in the `$redirs` array.. i would not recommend using this @Sander Visser is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$new_URL = array(
                'old-page.php' => 'new-page.php',
                'old-page2.php' => 'new-page2.php',
                'old-page3.php' => 'new-page3.php',
                'old-page4.php' => 'new-page4.php',
                'old-page5.php' => 'new-page5.php',
                'old-page6.php' => 'new-page6.php',
                'old-page7.php' => 'new-page7.php',
                'old-page8.php' => 'new-page8.php',
                'old-page9.php' => 'new-page9.php',

        );

if (isset($_GET['req']))
{
    if(array_key_exists($_GET['req'], $new_URL))
    {
        $loc = 'http://www.example.co.uk/'.$new_URL[$_GET['req']];
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location: '.$loc.'');
    }else{
        echo 'requested URL not found!',
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the requested url is always set in the `$new_URL` array.. i would not recommend using this @Sander Visser is a better solution