# PHP URL Param redirects - with wildcards/regex

Tags: php, regex, redirect, parameters, wildcard

I recently [found this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951319/php-array-for-redirecting-pages) for doing php url variable to header location redirects.

It's so much more manageable compared to htaccess for mass redirects, however one thing I want to next work out, how I can use regex to achieve what you can do with htaccess where request/(.*) goes to destination/$1.

My grasping is on that you use preg_match or preg_replace or something. How can I achieve something like the below, preferably keeping it short like this if possible. (I know this is wrong btw, just for example sake).

```
preg_match($redirects['request(.*)'] = "$domain/destination/\1");
```

Basically to break it down, say I want to redirect `doma.in/pics` to `domain.tld/pictures`, I have htaccess redirect that to `doma.in/index?req=pics`, where index is the script file and req is the parameter used.

And then using the script I have a line like `$redirects['pics'] = "$domain/pictures";`, where `$domain` variable is tied to `http://domain.tld`.

That works great, however I want to take this a step further with regex and send anything `pics/*stuff*`, aka `doma.in/index?req=pics/*stuff*` to `$domain/pictures/*stuff*`.

Here's an example of how things look using this script for doing many redirects.

```
$redirects['request'] = "$domain/dest";
$redirects['request2'] = "$domain/dest2";
$redirects['request3'] = "$domain/dest3";
```

Even though I've linked the post at the top that I got the script I'm using, here's the code:

```
if(isset($_GET['req']) && isset($redirects[$_GET['req']])) {
    $loc = htmlspecialchars($redirects[$_GET['req']]);
    header("Location: " . $loc);
    exit();
}
    header("Location: $domain");
```

With the $redirects lines being included above this, which I have in included files.

Comment: FYI, `isset()` can receive multiple arguments.  `htmlspecialchars()` is what you are meant to call before adding data into an html document, right?

Comment: @mickmackusa Yup, you mentioned it on the last answer haha, which is handy to know.  :) Also yea I take it with htmlspecialchars wouldn't be any point here as it's not getting printed on page, though if it was, then yes, so I left that out with my updated script lol. Thanks for the massive help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated script

I've completely overhauled this script, now I have realised a lot more that this is all an array that we're doing here with each redirect just adding to it. Also I've learnt a lot more about functions, and it's now extremely portable while also doing a lot more.

Here is the full new script. It's a beast compared to the previous, but the previous was so messy.

```
function redirects($config) {                           // Create a redirects(); function with the inputted array set as $config

    // Config Variables
    $req = $config['param'];                                // Assign $req to the $config param value 
    $dir = $config['dir'];                                  // Assign $dir to the $config dir value
    $domain = $config['domain'];                            // Assign $domain to the $config domain value
    $_404   = $config['404'];                               // Assign $_404 to this $config 404 value

    $_referer = $config['referer'];                         // Assign $referer_ to the referer value
    $referer = 'referer='.$_referer;                        // Assign $referer to the full referer param

    if (isset($_GET[$_referer])) {
        if ($_GET[$_referer] == $_referer) {                    // If this script's referer exists,
            echo "Do not loop back to the script!";             // Throw a warning
            exit();                                             // & exit
        }                                                       // Otherwise continue
    }

    if (isset($_GET[$req]) && !empty($_GET[$req])) {                // If a req parameter exists & isn't empty, continue
        $req = $_GET[$req];                                         // Assign $req to $_GET[$req]

        // Create the arrays
        $redirects = $wildcards = $halfwilds = array();             // Create the arrays needed, so if there's not at least one redirect done, which would be what creates the array otherwise, there won't be a 500 error due to it. 

        // Redirect includes
        foreach (glob($dir) as $filename) {                         // Search for all redirect php files at $dir location
            include $filename;                                      // Include those files
        }

        // Leading & Trailing Slashes
        $req = '/'.trim($req, '/').'/';                             // Add a leading & trailing slash to $req param if non existent
            
        function redir_editkeys($array) {                           // Create an editkeys(); function and pass the specified array as $array
            $keys = array_keys($array);                                 // Extract the keys of the array as values of $keys array
            foreach ($keys as &$value) {
                $value = '/'.trim($value, '/').'/';                     // Add a leading & trailing slash to $keys values if non existent
            }
            return array_combine($keys, $array);                        // Replace the original array's keys with the modified keys & return
        }

        // Referer
        function referer($redir, $referer, $domain) {               // Create a referer(); function and pass to it $redir, $referer, & $domain.
            if (strpos($redir, $domain) !==false) {                     // Using $domain, check $redir for a match.
                $redir = $redir.'?'.$referer;                           // If there's a match, add the referer param
            }   return $redir;                                          // Return the edited $redir, or if no match, return without editing
        }

        // Redirects
        $redirects = redir_editkeys($redirects);                    // Edit $redirects keys using editkeys();
        if (isset($redirects[$req])) {                              // Check that $redirects[$req] exists
            $redir = $redirects[$req];                              // Assign $redir to $redirects[$req];
            $redir = referer($redir, $referer, $domain);            // If it does, run referer();
            header("Location: $redir");                             // & Redirect
            exit();                                                 
        }

        // Wildcards
        $wildcards = redir_editkeys($wildcards);                    // Edit $wildcards keys using editkeys();
        foreach ($wildcards as $key => $value) {                    // Assign variables to $wildcards keys & values
            if (strpos($req, $key) !== false) {                     // Using $key, check $req for a match
                $wild = substr($req, strlen($key));                 // Extract everything after the match as $wild
                $req = substr($req, 0, strlen($key));               // Extract the matching part at the beginning as $req
                if (isset($wildcards[$req])) {                      // Check that $wildcards[$req] exists
                    $redir = $wildcards[$req];                      // Assign $redir to $wildcards[$req]
                    $redir = $redir.$wild;                          // Attach $wild onto $redir
                    $redir = referer($redir, $referer, $domain);    // If it does, run referer();
                    header("Location: $redir");                     // & Redirect
                    exit();             
                }
            }
        }

        // Half Wilds
        $halfwilds = redir_editkeys($halfwilds);                    // Edit $halfwilds keys using editkeys();
        foreach ($halfwilds as $key => $value) {                    // Assign variables to $halfwilds keys & values
            if (strpos($req, $key) !== false) {                     // Using $key, check $req for a match
                $req = substr($req, 0, strlen($key));               // Extract the matching part at the beginning as $req
                if (isset($halfcards[$req])) {                      // Check that $halfwilds[$req] exists
                    $redir = $halfwilds[$req];                      // Assign $redir to $halfwilds[$req]
                    $redir = referer($redir, $referer, $domain);    // If it does, run referer();
                    header("Location: $redir");                     // & Redirect
                    exit();             
                }
            }
        }

        // 404
        $req = "req=".trim($req,'/')."&";                           // Attach the param name to the $req value for the 404 redirect if it's not empty and remove the slashes.
    }   
    else { $req = ''; }                                         // If no req param, or if empty, unset $req
    header("Location: ".$domain.$_404."?".$req.$referer);       // If there's no match, redirect to this location.
}
```

We call this script by:

```
redirects(
    array( // Config
        'param'   => 'req',                   //  Param name                 ||  Set the name of the url param. Here it is "req".
        'dir'     => 'redirects/*/*.php',     //  Redirect file(s) location  ||  Set the location to look for the file(s) you store your redirects. Here I have my files in sub folders of a rediects folder. Do not put a leading slash infront, use "../" etc as it must be relative, not absolute..
        'domain'  => 'http://domain.tld',     //  Your domain                ||  Set your website's domain name here. This'll be used to check whether redirects go to it and if the referer is needed.
        '404'     => '/',                     //  404 location               ||  Set the location 404s will go to. Hereit is just my homepage, so I've put "/".
        'referer' => 'redirector'             //  Referer param              ||  Set the value of the referer param that will be used in redirects to the same site so we can stop 404s resulting in a loop.
    )
);
```

To do simple redirects, we can do:

```
$redirects['request1'] = "$domain/dest1";
$redirects['request2'] = "$domain/dest2";
```

To do wildcards, we can do: (make sure to add trailing slashes on the end unless it's a destination such as as a query string)

```
$wildcards['request3'] = "$domain/dest3/";
$wildcards['request4'] = "$domain/dest4/";
```

And I also have added a half wildcards, so if you want to send `request5/anypath` to just `$domain/dest5`, and not `dest5/anypath`, we can do:

```
$halfwilds['request5'] = "$domain/dest5";
$halfwilds['request6'] = "$domain/dest6";
```

Let's split this into chunks and take a look at what each part is doing:

---

1. Configuration:

---

First we start the `redirects();` function with the `$config` array as the argument. Then we assign variables to each setting.

```
function redirects($config) {                           // Create a redirects(); function with the inputted array set as $config

    // Config Variables
    $req = $config['param'];                                // Assign $req to the $config param value 
    $dir = $config['dir'];                                  // Assign $dir to the $config dir value
    $domain = $config['domain'];                            // Assign $domain to the $config domain value
    $_404   = $config['404'];                               // Assign $_404 to this $config 404 value

    $_referer = $config['referer'];                         // Assign $referer_ to the referer value
    $referer = 'referer='.$_referer;                        // Assign $referer to the full referer param
```

We have two variables for the referer, one for the referer value, and the second to join up as a full param for use in the redirects.

---

2. Referer check

---

I've firstly included a check for if this script's referer param exists in the request, and just simply say `"Do not loop back to the script!"`, and then `exit();` the script.

```
    if (isset($_GET[$_referer])) {
        if ($_GET[$_referer] == $_referer) {                    // If this script's referer exists,
            echo "Do not loop back to the script!";             // Throw a warning
            exit();                                             // & exit
        }                                                       // Otherwise continue
    }
```

---

3. The arrays and includes

---

Next up, if there is no match for the referer param in the request, we open an if for when the req param exists and is not empty, create the empty arrays, and then include where we have stated in the config we're putting our redirects.

```
    if (isset($_GET[$req]) && !empty($_GET[$req])) {                // If a req parameter exists & isn't empty, continue
        $req = $_GET[$req];                                         // Assign $req to $_GET[$req]

        // Create the arrays
        $redirects = $wildcards = $halfwilds = array();             // Create the arrays needed, so if there's not at least one redirect done, which would be what creates the array otherwise, there won't be a 500 error due to it. 

        // Redirect includes
        foreach (glob($dir) as $filename) {                         // Search for all redirect php files at $dir location
            include $filename;                                      // Include those files
        }
```

From my understanding with the way php works, this actually has a benefit putting the includes inside the if, that if the condition isn't met, which would be the case when the request has no req param, the includes won't even get processed.

---

4. Leading & Trailing slashes

---

With how things were before with the previous script, we had to make sure we added slashes at the end of the redirect keys, and send requests to the script with trailing slashes at the end of the param. Let's take the need away from doing this by using `trim();` for if it exists mixed with adding it back on, plus a leading slash too to ensure `strpos();` won't match 'cat-dog/' when we wanted to look for 'dog/'.

```
        // Leading & Trailing Slashes
        $req = '/'.trim($req, '/').'/';                             // Add a leading & trailing slash to $req param if non existent
            
        function redir_editkeys($array) {                           // Create an editkeys(); function and pass the specified array as $array
            $keys = array_keys($array);                                 // Extract the keys of the array as values of $keys array
            foreach ($keys as &$value) {
                $value = '/'.trim($value, '/').'/';                     // Add a leading & trailing slash to $keys values if non existent
            }
            return array_combine($keys, $array);                        // Replace the original array's keys with the modified keys & return
        }
```

Here we've created a function called `editkeys();` which makes a new array of the keys of whatever array you pass to it, does a foreach to modify those keys and then put them back into the original array, replacing the original keys.

---

5. Destination domain check for if referer param is needed

---

If we are sending the destination's 404 requests to the script, we want to stop redirect loops for redirects to that destination that end in 404s. We could just have the referer param to always be added, but that could risk bugging something up depending on that destination's website configuration's handling of query strings. So let's do a function to check for whether the passed destination goes to `$domain`, add the referer to it if true and return it back.

```
        // Referer
        function referer($redir, $referer, $domain) {               // Create a referer(); function and pass to it $redir, $referer, & $domain.
            if (strpos($redir, $domain) !==false) {                     // Using $domain, check $redir for a match.
                $redir = $redir.'?'.$referer;                           // If there's a match, add the referer param
            }   return $redir;                                          // Return the edited $redir, or if no match, return without editing
        }
```

---

6. Redirecting

---

Next we have the part that puts together the redirects. Firstly we have the simple redirects. Firstly, we run the `$redirects` array though the `editkeys();` function, then it checks if the matching key is in the array, run the `referer();` function above on the destination and then redirect to it.

```
        // Redirects
        $redirects = redir_editkeys($redirects);                    // Edit $redirects keys using editkeys();
        if (isset($redirects[$req])) {                              // Check that $redirects[$req] exists
            $redir = $redirects[$req];                              // Assign $redir to $redirects[$req];
            $redir = referer($redir, $referer, $domain);            // If it does, run referer();
            header("Location: $redir");                             // & Redirect
            exit();                                                 
        }
```

Secondly is the wildcards. We run the `$wildcards` array through the `editkeys();` function, run a `foreach();` on the array to look for a matching key, get everything after the match as `$wild`, get only the match as `$req`, check the `$req` value exists as a key in the array, get that key's destination, attach the $wild on, then run the check for if referer is needed, redirect and bam.

```
        // Wildcards
        $wildcards = redir_editkeys($wildcards);                    // Edit $wildcards keys using editkeys();
        foreach ($wildcards as $key => $value) {                    // Assign variables to $wildcards keys & values
            if (strpos($req, $key) !== false) {                     // Using $key, check $req for a match
                $wild = substr($req, strlen($key));                 // Extract everything after the match as $wild
                $req = substr($req, 0, strlen($key));               // Extract the matching part at the beginning as $req
                if (isset($wildcards[$req])) {                      // Check that $wildcards[$req] exists
                    $redir = $wildcards[$req];                      // Assign $redir to $wildcards[$req]
                    $redir = $redir.$wild;                          // Attach $wild onto $redir
                    $redir = referer($redir, $referer, $domain);    // If it does, run referer();
                    header("Location: $redir");                     // & Redirect
                    exit();             
                }
            }
        }
```

Then we have half wildcards, which does more or less the same. I've not really got any real reason for this one myself, but there are reasons for it for sure, such as that you've got rid of a whole portfolio gallery and want to send requests to that and sub requests to the images etc back to the portfolio, this will do the job. So it's an included part of the script.

```
        // Half Wilds
        $halfwilds = redir_editkeys($halfwilds);                    // Edit $halfwilds keys using editkeys();
        foreach ($halfwilds as $key => $value) {                    // Assign variables to $halfwilds keys & values
            if (strpos($req, $key) !== false) {                     // Using $key, check $req for a match
                $req = substr($req, 0, strlen($key));               // Extract the matching part at the beginning as $req
                if (isset($halfcards[$req])) {                      // Check that $halfwilds[$req] exists
                    $redir = $halfwilds[$req];                      // Assign $redir to $halfwilds[$req]
                    $redir = referer($redir, $referer, $domain);    // If it does, run referer();
                    header("Location: $redir");                     // & Redirect
                    exit();             
                }
            }
        }
```

I did want to try to do a function to save this largely duplicated code, but `foreach();`'s are darn awkward.

---

7. 404

---

Then we have the 404 redirect that sends back home whatever requests to the script that either have no match with the request as a req param, or just with the referer param if there was no req param or if it is empty.

```
        // 404
        $req = "req=".trim($req,'/')."&";                           // Attach the param name to the $req value for the 404 redirect if it's not empty and remove the slashes.
    }   
    else { $req = ''; }                                         // If no req param, or if empty, unset $req
    header("Location: ".$domain.$_404."?".$req.$referer);       // If there's no match, redirect to this location.
}
```

---

And that's the script.

---

Now, to send dead requests to the script.

Apache / Litespeed / Openlitespeed (htaccess)

---

At the bottom of your htaccess, add this:

```
############# Rewrite dead requests to redirector with uri as query
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !referer=redirector [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /redirect.php?req=$1 [R=301,L]
#############
```

Nginx

---

Add this in the server's (vhost) conf:

```
############# Send dead requests to redirector with uri as query
error_page 404 = @redirects;
location @redirects {
    if ($query_string !~ referer=redirector {
        rewrite ^/(.*)(.php?) /redirect.php?req=$1 redirect;
    }
}
#############
```

I'm using Nginx now, moving away from OpenLitespeed since a weird issue came up that Nginx didn't have at all. So been some fun figuring out Nginx conf way of doing things. One thing I noticed was that by rewriting extension requests to no extensions, requests that get sent else where you'll notice have .php added on the end. So I've got it to exclude the extension in the rewrite here. Also doing these wildcard redirects in a location for `error_page 404`, is a tonne lot easier than trying to set in an `if` to ignore existent files/folders.

---

Removing the referer param on requests at the destination.

---

While trying to do the same with nginx what I'd done with htaccess, remove the referer param, which I was having fun trying to do, I realised that was a bit of a flawed solution anyway because it removes the whole query.
In comes using PHP instead, this function to achieve just that, removing a single param:

```
function strip_param($url,$param) {
  if (isset($_GET[$param])) {                     // Check that param exists
    $base_url = strtok($url,'?');                 // Get the base url
    $parsed_url = parse_url($url);                // Parse it
    $query = $parsed_url['query'];                // Get the query string
    parse_str($query,$params);                    // Convert parameters into array
    unset($params[$param]);                       // Delete the one you want
    $new_query = http_build_query($params);       // Rebuild query string
    $new_url = $base_url.'?'.$new_query;          // Rebuild the url
    $url = rtrim($new_url,'?');                   // If now no query, remove ending ?
    return header("Location: $url");              // Redirect
  } 
}

//  How to use
//
//  Place the above function anywhere you include above content of where you need it, such as a functions file.
//  The below, put this somewhere at the top before content.

// Strip params from requests
strip_param($webpage_URI,'referer');              // The $webpage_URI value is:    "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This function we can [give props to this person for](https://newbedev.com/php-remove-parameter-from-url-php-code-example).
This is what lead me to just start cloning the way it was commented. It is such a tidy, readable way to do things. And even though my script before was short, it wasn't tidy, and it wasn't exactly sweet. But oh I'm so glad to get functions now. Well recommended!!

---

Thanks Mick for again the few tips for improving that bit more.
Had a bit of fun with 500 errors because I botched up when I decided to name the half wildcards `$half_wildcards` instead of `$wildcards_half`, I didn't update all of them lol. I've changed this now to `$halfwilds`, as I suddenly thought of it, which is the same amount of characters to `$wildcards` and `$redirects` so that's sweet consistency there. It differentiates it more too, which in turn just makes things less confusing.

Also this brought up the one problem that would arise if someone used this just say for `$wildcards`, or `$redirects`, or in my case, both, but not `$halfwilds`.. the associated array doesn't get created if no redirects for it exist, which would cause a 500. So I've created the empty arrays so they will always exist and not cause an error.

---

Updated the script a slight moving the array key variable assignations around so they don't spam the logs if you don't have them set to ignore warnings for undefined arrays and variables etc. I've got those logs now set to critical, because it is annoying but not here to be lazy with this script. Also edited the editkeys function name to `redir_editkeys` upon realising nested functions still darn well act as global defining them wise. grr php has it's quirks.

Comment: Geez, this is a massive writeup.  I needed two coffees and I think I missed a birthday while reading.  You've put in a big effort.  `if (isset($_GET[$param]) !== false) {` can be `if (isset($_GET[$param])) {` because `isset()` only returns a boolean value.

Comment: `if (strpos($redir, $domain) !==false) { $redir = $redir.'?'.$referer; return $redir; } return $redir;` doesn't need the inner `return` -- the `return` after the condition will do.  Also, `$value = '/'.ltrim($value, '/'); $value = rtrim($value, '/').'/';` can be `$value = '/' . trim($value, '/') . '/';`. You don't need to overwrite `$array`, just `return array_combine($keys, $array);`.

Comment: Ahhh yes that makes sense! Not sure what my thinking was there lol, but yep totally no point to that double up because if the condition is met, it's returned as the edited `$redir`, however it'll be the original if it wasn't met. Kind of the point of `if`s xd

Comment: Oooh and thanks for that about the `trim`. sweet! And also yup, that makes sense too about array combine. Thanks for those!!

Comment: I've updated with the improvements that you brought up, changed the param check to an `!empty` instead of `isset` as that makes more sense, so I can edit the `$req` value inside that condition at the bottom to be the full param, so then I only need a single 404 redirect, so if the condition wasn't met, the no `req` param gets added on that redirect at all. Plus I've added so the arrays get created even if you don't do any associated redirects, which otherwise would end up as a 500 which I spotted lol.

Comment: Plus, with the condition now being a check that it's not empty, I can have the adding slashes on the param also as a simple one liner `trim()` instead of ltrim and rtrim. That'd add double slashes if the param is empty when it was `isset()`, so another reason for using `!empty()` here haha.. not that this really changes much when I'm now removing the slashes at the end for 404s, which is what want anyway, but still good to know haha

Answer (score 1):

### This is a long read, plus it is messy way of doing this. See my accepted answer for a much better way to do this.

I thought that `ltrim()` was what I wanted, seeing on other answers that if for example I specify 0 as what to remove, 01 will become 1, 001 will become 01, and 10 will be left as 10, 100 as 100 and so on. However this was not turning out to be the case. and instead it would strip all instances of the stated characters. Though it wasn't doing it with the slash, so confused.

This however does it correctly:

```
if (strpos($get, $req) === 0) {
    $get = substr($get, strlen($req));
}
return $get;
```

[Thanks to this answer for this one liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58805069/2943403).

All I'm doing here with this script is just assigning `$redirects['request']` to the associated value, like with any other variable value assignments. And the `$_GET['req']` already does the job to get well whatever the parameter is, so no complicated preg or regex or anything.

So with that `substr()`, we can take the `$_GET['req']` and do the following:

```
$req = "pics/";
$get = $_GET['req'];
$wild = strpos($get, $req) === 0
    ? substr($get, strlen($req))
    : $get;

$redirects["pics/$wild"] = "$domain/pictures/$wild";
```

This takes `pics/*stuff*` and removes the `pics/` so the value of $wild equals just `*stuff*`, and so I just use that in the redirect to make a wildcard and taadaa.

This is completely functional, but let's make this even better to save remembering this code each time which is a fair bit.

Create a function like this above the redirects:

```
function wildcard($req) {
    $get = $_GET['req'];
    return strpos($get, $req) === 0
        ? substr($get, strlen($req))
        : $get;
}
```

By calling `wildcard('pics/');`, the `$req` equals `pics/`.

We can use this in redirects like:

```
$req = "pics/";
$wild = wildcard($req);
$redirects[$req.$wild] = "$domain/pictures/$wild";
```

It's still a bit more than I hoped for, so the idea I've had is to call `$req` as a global in the function, like this:

```
function wild() {
    $get = $_GET['req']; global $req;
    return strpos($get, $req) === 0
        ? substr($get, strlen($req))
        : $get;
}
```

And then do the redirect like:

```
$req = "pics/";
$redirects[$req.wild()] = "$domain/pictures/".wild();
```

That becomes a much shorter single line. Though with the conflict around using globals, I've just put it back to as before but instead of repeatedly assigning `$wild`, just put `$req` back inside `wild()` and have it be like:

```
$req = "pics/";    $redirects[$req.wild($req)] = "$domain/pictures/".wild($req);
```

It's still shorter anyway and isn't much to it over the brackets being empty.

P.S, This method, you want to include the trailing slash on the parameter so results don't get messy.
In order to achieve to be able to send `pics` to the `$domain/pictures`, we want to have a trailing slash at the end of the parameter. In your redirect rule in htaccess to send requests as a parameter to the script, add a trailing slash on the end. So if you're using Apache or Litespeed, you can do the following in htaccess to send all requests to your script as a parameter with the trailing slash like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?req=$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Make sure this is at the bottom so it doesn't take priority over other rules.

Also added a precautionary `rtrim()` to the script to remove the trailing slash in the header location, so if you want to link anything that doesn't remove trailing slashes on file links, it doesn't go to a dead link. As again the slashes weren't being effected by what behaviour I discovered as mentioned at top, this is fine here.

Here is how you can have things now.

```
function wild($req) {
    $get = $_GET['req'];
    return strpos($get, $req) === 0
        ? substr($get, strlen($req))
        : $get;
}

$domain = "http://domain.tld";

// Redirects
$req = "request1/";    $redirects[$req.wild($req)] = "$domain/dest1/".wild($req);
$req = "request2/";    $redirects[$req.wild($req)] = "$domain/dest2/".wild($req);
$req = "request3/";    $redirects[$req.wild($req)] = "$domain/dest3/".wild($req);

// Run Script
if (isset($_GET['req'], $redirects[$_GET['req']])) {
    $loc = htmlspecialchars($redirects[$_GET['req']]);
    header("Location: " . rtrim($loc,"/"));
    exit();
}

// If no match in the redirects, redirect to this location.
header("Location: $domain");
```

Now, this has one flaw if the destination is sending non existent requests to the script, if a destination, which is going to be guaranteed with wildcards, is non existent for the request, well.back it goes to the script and bam you have a redirect loop.

My way of solving this is to add `?referer=doma.in` to the end of the header location, and in the htaccess on domain.tld, exclude non existent requests with that query string from redirecting back to the script.

So that looks like:

```
$loc = htmlspecialchars($redirects[$_GET['req']]).'?referer=doma.in';
```

And in the htaccess of domain.tld, place a rewritecond above the existing rule like so to exclude the query string:

```
# Ignore these referer queries
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !referer=doma.in [NC]

# Send dead requests to doma.in with uri as query
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://doma.in/?referer=domain.tld&req=$1/ [R=301,L]
```

For good measure I also added a referer on the redirect for the domain.tld.

Now, as a bonus, to hide the refer query on requests to tidy things up, let's add below:

```
# Send dead requests with referer query to home (or 404 or wherever)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "referer=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /?req=$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove referer query from requests
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "referer=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/? [R=301,L]
```

We need to send dead referer query requests somewhere before we remove the query, otherwise we'd be back at step one. I have the dead requests sent to my homepage with the request uri as a parameter so that can still know what the request url was.

And job done. But as an extra bonus, let's make external/non wildcard redirects not have a query. So back in the script, change the script to be like so:

```
$get = $_GET['req'];
$loc = $redirects[$get];
$wildloc = $wildcards[$get];

// Run Script
if(isset($get) && isset($loc) || isset($wildloc)) {
    if(isset($wildcards[$get])) {
    $loc = rtrim($wildloc,'/').'?referer=hwl.li'; }
    $loc = rtrim(htmlspecialchars($loc),'/');
    header("Location: ".$loc);
    exit();
}
```

Here, I've moved things about with the `$_GET['req']` assigned to `$get`, `$redirects[$get]` assigned as `$loc`, `$wildcards[$get]` assigned to `$wildloc`, and call them in the issets, along with an extra isset after an `:`, aka `OR` for `$wildloc`.

And then have an if statement so `$wildcards` redirects use `$loc` assigned to `$wildloc`, and `$redirects` ones use the above one.

This way, we can have tidy redirects.

So now things look like:

```
// Wildcard function
function wild($req) {
    $get = $_GET['req'];
    return strpos($get, $req) === 0
        ? substr($get, strlen($req))
        : $get;
}

$domain = "http://domain.tld";

// Redirects
$req = "request1/";   $wildcards[$req.wild($req)] = "$domain/dest1/".wild($req);  // A wildcard redirect
$req = "request2/";    $wildcards[$req.wild($req)] = "$domain/dest2/".wild($req);  // A wildcard redirect
$redirects['request3/'] = "$domain/dest3/"; // Not a wildcard redirect

$get = $_GET['req'];
$loc = $redirects[$get];
$wildloc = $wildcards[$get];

// Run Script
if(isset($get) && isset($loc) || isset($wildloc)) {
    if(isset($wildcards[$get])) {
    $loc = rtrim($wildloc,'/').'?referer=hwl.li';}
    $loc = rtrim(htmlspecialchars($loc),'/');
    header("Location: ".$loc);
    exit();
}

// If no match in the redirects, redirect to this location.
header("Location: $domain/?req=$get");
```

This improves things so much and solves the redirect loop.

Edited this again slightly as what I did here with the query string being appended.. the `rtrim()` therefore was looking for a non existent trailing slash after that, not where we wanted it to be doing it, before. So now the `rtrim()` comes before. Doubles it up which is slightly annoying but at least it does the job right now.

Comment: Just so you know, `isset()` can receive multiple parameters.  `isset($_GET['req'], $redirects[$_GET['req']])`.  Also, using `strpos()` without explicitly checking `=== false` can lead to incorrect results in fringe cases.

Comment: Right this also does what is wanted which from the looks of it does the practically the same thing. `if (strpos($get, $req) === 0) $get = substr($get, strlen($req)); {return $get;}`

Comment: I have left a comment under the _bad_ post and indicated what is wrong with it.  I have also downvoted and voted to delete the old answer because it is misleading researchers.  We definitely don't want unstable answers getting copy-pasted into new answers.

Comment: ...you missed one occurrence in your last edit.  Also there is no benefit in declaring `$wild = wildcard($req);` three times in a row.  It remains unchanged.  Don't ask php to execute the same function with the same input for the same output.  Just re-use the variable.

Comment: I have made a substantiate edit of your post to improve the coding standard.  Please review the changes to make sure that it is still saying the same thing that you originally meant to say.  You are welcome to re-edit if needed.

Comment: Yup, it's actually shorter as a one liner with the check in place this one lol. Thanks for bringing that up. About the `wildcard()`, the issue is that needs to be after every `$req` as that is called in the `wildcard($req);`, which is unique each time and is the whole point of that function. But this gave me an idea of how to neaten it up, but now I've realised that `global $var` is a thing, I can just call the `$req` like that rather than by `wildcard($req);` that needs to be done each time...

Comment: So now I shortened from wildcard to just wild and I just need to do `wild()`, so done away with the assigning that to $wild, and just added `wild()` in place of where I had the `$wild` variables in the redirects. So much shorter.

Comment: General/Professional advice is to not use `global`. If you need a variable to be available within a function scope, pass it in as an argument instead of using `global`.

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit confused, while was going to edit what I changed and noticed you improved things while editing. I didn't save my edit I thought but apparently I did. How do I revert to your edit?

Comment: If you want to completely discard my attempt to improve the answer, you can `rollback` to another edit in the version history.  Click on the blue text that says "edited 1 hour ago" to see the history. I hope that your change will be better than mine if you are going to discard mine.  Your old linked answer is probably deleted by now.

Comment: Yea I didn't want to discard what you did, just caught me offguard lol. Apparently I didn't accidently save my edit, I think I might of pressed the back so I saw the page as from an hour ago lol

Comment: Updated with my edits now, see you just simply tidied things up a bit so I appreciate that. And decided against global as while it did give a benefit tidiness wise, there isn't much in it when I call the function in the redirects in the same fashion without assigning it as `$wild` variable.

Comment: Even if `isset($get) && isset($loc) || isset($wildloc)` _does_ work as intended, I strongly recommend using parethetical grouping so that future developers instantly know exactly how the logic _should_ be.